# Чи потрібно писати дефіс між номером будинку і його літерою?

Tags: орфографія, пунктуація

Цікавить не написання адреси в цілому, а саме вулиця і будинок у випадку, якщо номер будинку містить в собі ще й літеру.
Наприклад, "Дегтярівська **49Г**" чи "Дегтярівська **49-Г**"?

Помітила неоднакове написання тоді, коли в паспортіоднієї особи реєстрація місця проживання зафіксована за адресою "Дегтярівська 49А", а в паспорті іншої "Дегтярівська 49-а".

Можливо, і справді немає єдиного стандарту для написання адреси.Але чи не можуть виникнути проблеми, скажімо, з органами державної влади, якщо написати в якихось документах адресу з дефісом в той час як в паспорті його немає?

На [офіційному сайті КНЕУ](https://kneu.edu.ua/ua/University_en/map/korp2_3/), один з корпусів та гуртожитків якого знаходиться за цією адресою вказано наступний варіант:

> Адреса: м.Київ, вул. Дегтярівська, 49-г

[Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=Vne7Wty6MInTwQKI3arADw&q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%2049%D0%B3&oq=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%2049%D0%B3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i10k1j38j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l2.88174.88577.0.89472.2.2.0.0.0.0.242.400.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.395...35i39k1.0.N69IPe14EGk) же видає варіант написання без дефіса:

> Корпус №2 КНЕУ, вулиця Дегтярівська, 49Г, Київ, 02000

*Чи потрібно писати дефіс між, власне, номером будинку і його літерою*, а також, *чи принципово, що ця літера повинна бути великою/малою?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так, справді, пишуть по-різному. Навіть тут:

Наголошую, що це не сайт про українську мову, правила написання тощо, але все ж це [офіційний веб-портал Верховної Ради України](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/v0048359-09). У пункті 7.5. пише так:

> Номер будинку вказується арабськими цифрами: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0.
>
> Номер кутового будинку зазначається через дріб.
>
> Приклад: 7/17
>
> **Якщо в номері будинку є *літера*, вона *зазначається великою без пропуску від номера*.**
>
> *Приклад*: **17Б**

Щоправда ця постанова стосується **лише** «Правил внесення відомостей про виборців до автоматизованої інформаційно-телекомунікаційної системи «Державний реєстр виборців» (nb!).

Однак у [правописі 1999 («проєкт»), § 28](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/28.html) пише так (*насправді цього маєм і дотримуватись*):

> е) **літерні найменування** паралельних класів у школах, **різних будинків з однаковими номерами на тій самій вулиці**: 7-А, 10-Б; **вул. Зодчих, буд. 26-А**

Частину такої ж інформації подає і [чинний (2015) правопис § 25.4](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par25p4e):

> Через дефіс пишуться [...] e) літерні найменування паралельних класів у школах:
>   *7‑А, 10‑В*.

Проте за аналогією робимо висновок, що маємо писати «вул. Дегтярівська, 49-г» або ж «вул. Дегтярівська, 49-Г».

Comment: Мабуть, варто також додати, що [проект правопису 2018](//mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/gromadske-obgovorennya/2018/08/15/novoi-redaktsii-pravopisu.pdf) на с. 35 теж містить правило, аналогічне до запропонованого в проекті-1999: «[З дефісом пишемо] д) числівниково-літерні найменування класів, будинків, корпусів, поштових
відділень тощо: 7-А клас, 10-В клас, будúнок No 28-Г, кóрпус 3-А; Кúїв-1».